# After Trigger with JOIN Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, inner-join

TASK: Create an AFTER TRIGGER to accomplish a condition from a JOIN. The Trigger would be in table_1 when some record is created. Meanwhile, table_2 has a common column with some parameters that the condition needs to have.

Every time that the Result <> 1 AND Status <> 3 in table_2 and ALERT should be sent

```
-- QUERY WITH JOIN TABLE_1 ON TABLE_2

-- MOCK TABLE 

-- Table_1 as A  |    Table_2 as B

   A.LotCode | A.LineNumber  | B.Result  |  B.Status 

    00000    |   xxxx        |   1       |   3
    00001    |   xxxx        |   2       |   4

-- The LotCode 00001 should send it through email because satisfy the condition
```

```
CREATE TRIGGER FullfillOrderQCResult
ON Table_1
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
      -----DECLARE VARIABLES-----

      DECLARE @LOTNUMBER VARCHAR(50)
      DECLARE @ACTIONPEFORMED VARCHAR(MAX)
      DECLARE @ITEM INT
      DECLARE @RESULT TINYINT
      DECLARE @STATUS TINYINT

      SELECT @LOTNUMBER = A.LotCode, @ITEM = A.LineNumber, @RESULT = B.Result, @STATUS = B.Status
      FROM inserted AS A
      JOIN Table_2 AS B
      ON A.LotCode = B.DocumentID2
    
      -----CONDITION WHEN I INSERT A VALUE-----

      IF (@RESULT <> 1 AND @STATUS <> 3)
      BEGIN     
          SET @ACTIONPEFORMED = 
              N'Hello, ' + '<br>' + '<br>'
              + N'  The following LOT NUMBER: ' + @LOTNUMBER + ' has not been approved for this Item: '  

          EXEC MSDB.DBO.SP_SEND_DBMAIL
            @PROFILE_NAME = 'SQLMail',
            @RECIPIENTS = 'TEST@gmail.com',
            @SUBJECT = 'LOT NON-Approved',
            @BODY = @ACTIONPEFORMED,
            @IMPORTANCE = 'HIGH',
            @BODY_FORMAT = 'HTML'
      END
      ELSE 
            PRINT 'ALL GOOD MY FRIEND'
END
```

```
TESTING THE TRIGGER

--------INSERT VALUES------------------

INSERT INTO Table_1 (LotCode,LineNumber)
values ('00000','xxxx')

-----EXISTING VALUES-----

INSERT INTO Table_2 (CreationUser,DocumentID1,DocumentID2,DocumentID3,Result,Status)
values ('JL','00000','00000','00000',2,3)
```

Comment: You have made the classic 101 trigger mistake, and that is assuming that Inserted (&Deleted) have only one row, when in fact they can have 0-N and you must handle that.

Comment: Aside from that, what is your question?

Comment: Hello, @DaleK I appreciated the comments and the script. I'm still learning regarding triggers but I have never done some triggers with JOIN. My question is why is not triggering when I enter a value in the table? I know it's a dumb question.  To answer you about the "ALL GOOD MY FRIEND" is for debugging when the parameters are (Result = 1 or Status = 3). I followed your code and I still have the same issue not triggering the email when I insert the test values. I might take a look at the second script that you wrote (I haven't created anything regarding the Event into a queue). Thanks

Comment: Its not triggering because your conditions aren't being met. You really need to show your exact sample data. But based on what you are showing the entry in the Table_2 has a status of 3 which is OK, if you add a status of 4 you'll find it sends the email. See this [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=d62ae56b833b4c1c8cc1b0070b4ee37b) - you don't need a trigger to test your join, just test it on the real tables. You should really be providing such a [mre] as part of your question.

Comment: Hey @DaleK, thank you for sharing the code. I was having a problem with the ACTIONPEFORMED but now I changed it and it works. Greetings, I learn something regarding Triggers and JOINS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following shows you how to handle the fact that `Inserted` might have multiple rows. This is really not ideal behaviour for a trigger, because you have to process the results RBAR (row by agonising row), which is slow by itself, let alone the fact that you are sending an email.

```
CREATE TRIGGER FullfillOrderQCResult
ON Table_1
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -----DECLARE VARIABLES-----

    DECLARE @ACTIONPEFORMED varchar(max), @Id int;

    SELECT A.LotCode, A.LineNumber, CONVERT(bit, 0) Done, IDENTITY(int) id -- Use your own id if you have one, just need to uniquely identify each row.
    INTO #FullfillOrderQCResult_temp
    FROM Inserted AS A
    INNER JOIN Table_2 AS B ON A.LotCode = B.DocumentID2
    WHERE B.Result <> 1 and B.[Status] <> 3;

    WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #FullfillOrderQCResult_temp WHERE Done = 0) BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1 @Id = id, @ACTIONPEFORMED = 
            N'Hello, ' + '<br>' + '<br>'
            + N'The following LOT NUMBER: ' + LotCode + ' has not been approved for this Item: ' + LineNumber
        FROM #FullfillOrderQCResult_temp
        WHERE Done = 0;

        EXEC MSDB.DBO.SP_SEND_DBMAIL
            @PROFILE_NAME = 'SQLMail',
            @RECIPIENTS = 'TEST@gmail.com',
            @SUBJECT = 'LOT NON-Approved',
            @BODY = @ACTIONPEFORMED,
            @IMPORTANCE = 'HIGH',
            @BODY_FORMAT = 'HTML';

        UPDATE #FullfillOrderQCResult_temp SET Done = 1 WHERE id = @Id;
    END;
END;
```

I don't know whether you would still want the concept of `'ALL GOOD MY FRIEND'` because you could have none, some or all rows with issues. Anyway I assume `print` is only for debugging.

---

That said you would be much better off pushing an event into a queue and having a service process said event because triggers really should be as fast as possible. And adding an event to a queue could be handled in a set based manner e.g.

```
CREATE TRIGGER FullfillOrderQCResult
ON Table_1
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO MyEventQueue (A.LotCode, A.LineNumber) -- Any other information required to identify the records etc
        SELECT A.LotCode, A.LineNumber
        FROM Inserted AS A
        INNER JOIN Table_2 AS B ON A.LotCode = B.DocumentID2
        WHERE B.Result <> 1 and B.[Status] <> 3;
END;
```